# Smarty display from subdirectory

Tags: php, templates, smarty, smarty3

I can't get smarty to display a tpl file from a subdirectory.

a php file in the root is working great, but if the php file is in a subfolder the display method is not working.

I found out that the template path in smarty is a relative path. So for me it makes sense that display is not working because the path is wrong.

So I set the template path to

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/templates');
```

This is the templates folder which is part of the root directory.

But it's stoll not working either.

Any Ideas? : /

Edit:

Full Code:

```
require('../../../model/smarty/Smarty.class.php'); 
$smarty = new Smarty();
include "../../../model/smarty/smarty_config.php";

var_dump($smarty->getTemplateDir());

$smarty->assign('dummy','Smarty Dummy Place');

$smarty->display('indexNotLoggedIn.tpl');
```

The Include in the first line is a temporary solution to change the template path. It just does this:

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/templates/');
```

Answer (score 2):

You provide something like this:

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir('http://usrltowebpage.com/templates');
```

but you supposed to provide PATH not an URL:

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir('/home/mywebpage.com/public_html/templates');
```

To update:
why you are using

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

? - cant you just pass real path as a string?

Comment: Okay, I changed that. So I dumped my template path and it is /var/www/my_project/templates/ now, which is correct.

but displaying $smarty->display('index.tpl'); does still not work, even  if it is in the root of the template directory. : /

Comment: var_dump($smarty->getTemplateDir()); look if it's set correctly

Comment: It is correct. As I mentioned above the path now is /var/www/my_project/templates/.  But displaying the tpl is still not working

Comment: it is hard to think about it without the code. if you set template dir only once (for multiple dirs you must provide them as an array not a string) and the directory is set properly and the file path is /var/www/my_project/templates/index.tpl it must work :) maybe you misspell something

Comment: I double checked it now. If I copy the template path in the browser it opens exactly the right folder where the templates  are located. I'm going to update my current code in the top post.

Comment: I added the full code now.

This is working with a php file in the root directory. But not with a php file in a sub directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The path to the templates_c, configs and cache folder has also to be an absolute path.